# Can't access beta sector

Tags: starbound

I've defeated penguins, built Starmap Upgrade MK2 and used it. Now I have access to tier 2 items, but still can't go to the beta sector.

How do I go to the beta sector?

Comment: Remember that Starbound is in super-early beta, so bugs are expected. If the answers you get here don't work, file a bug report: either you have a bug or the UI has issues, and either one should be fixed: http://community.playstarbound.com/index.php?threads/general-bug-reports.34306/

Comment: I have the same problem, Exept I have beaten the boss 3 times and still no B in the map I can click on.

Answer (score 11):

Beam up to your ship and use the seat at the far right to access your navigation.

The first screen shows the planets and moons in orbit around you; anything here will take just 1 fuel to travel to. Right-click to zoom out twice until you get to the view of the Alpha Sector.

In Alpha Sector view you can now switch to the Beta Sector with the "B" button at the top right. From the Beta Sector view you can use WASD to pan around and left-click to zoom back in to planets.

[image: animated GIF]

Travelling to the Beta Sector will initially take 200 fuel. From there you can travel between moons and planets for just 1 fuel, planets orbiting the same star for 50 fuel, and planets in different solar systems for 200 fuel. You will need to use coal as fuel at this stage which is worth 2 fuel each.

Answer (score 0):

On your ship, in the Star Map you have now a little [B] on the top right. Click on it and select a planet to go.